# Laravel Mockery Failing Test

Tags: php, phpunit, tdd, mockery

I was just wondering, I am trying to create this testcase however it keeps failing. Is there something that I am missing with using Mockery?

```
 /** @test */
function can_store_podcast_thumbnail()
{
    $podcast = factory(Podcast::class)->make([
        'feed_thumbnail_location' => 'https://media.simplecast.com/podcast/image/279/1413649662-artwork.jpg',
    ]);

    $mockedService = Mockery::mock(\App\PodcastUploadService::class);
    $mockedService->shouldReceive('storePodcastThumbnail')
        ->with($podcast)
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(true);

    $podcastUploadService = new \App\PodcastUploadService();
    $podcastUploadService->storePodcastThumbnail($podcast);
}
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method storePodcastThumbnail(object(App\Podcast)) from Mockery_2_App_PodcastUploadService should be called
```

exactly 1 times but called 0 times.

Just wondering,

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use mockery to mock dependencies of the class you are testing

Comment: Hey, would you perhaps have an example?

Comment: I've added an example on how to use it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you want to test the Bar class, which depends on the Foo class:

```
/**
 * This is the Dependency class
 */
class Foo
{
    public function fooAction()
    {
        return 'foo action';
    }
}

/*
 * This is the class you want to test, which depends on Foo
 */
class Bar
{
    private $foo;

    public function __construct(Foo $foo)
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    public function barAction()
    {
        return $this->foo->fooAction();
    }
}
```

Now in your bar test, you will say that when you run `barAction()` you expect that `fooAction()` is called and return a mock result:

```
$fooMock = Mockery::mock(Foo::class);
$barTest = new Bar($fooMock);

$fooMock->shouldReceive('fooAction')->andReturn('mockReturn');

$result = $barTest->barAction();

$this->assertEquals('mockReturn', $result);
```

In the example I passed the Foo object at the constructor level, but works the same if you pass it at function level

I hope this helps!